# How to search all text files in Ack? (with --text option being now removed)

Tags: ack

Manual says that "The `--text` option has been removed.". It was setting the `--type` to text, i.e. `ack` was searching all text files regardless of their semantic category (i.e. in *.php files, *.txt files, *.cpp files, etc.). How to obtain this behavior in current version of `ack`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ack` without a `--type` predicate:

```
ack <search pattern>
```

It ignores binary files and searches all textual files regardless of file type.

Comment: This is not the same bahavior. As I have clearly described in question, ACK was searching in text files regardless of their semantic category, i.e. in *.php files, *.pl files, etc.

Comment: I have *clearly* edited my answer for you ;-)

Comment: Good luck with a minified js file. It's invisible to ack, even for those magical special type searching in other answers. I think it might be because of line length (3247 chars).

Answer (score 1):

ack 2 no longer has a `--text` option because ack 2's default behavior is to search all text files.

This means that

```
ack1 --text foo
```

is the same as

```
ack2 foo
```